# Manifest code to block specific carrier?

Tags: android

I would like to block either:

1. The entire cellphone carrier Sprint
2. The specific phones Sprint Hero and Sprint Moment

Is there a way to do this in the manifest file or any other code related means?

I want to block the Sprint Hero for the widget bug and the Moment for handling contacts incorrectly. A huge fail on the part of Sprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this in the
>   manifest file or any other code
>   related means?

You can block certain carriers in the Android Market, but you cannot block carriers or devices in the manifest, AFAIK.

Comment: Where in the market is the ability to block certain carriers?

Comment: That would be sufficient, I just need to hide my app, on the Market, from them.

Comment: Go into your application in the Market Developer Console. In the Publishing Options box, uncheck "All Locations". You will then get a long list of countries. Clicking on the name of the country will unfold a list of carriers (though some countries only have "All Carriers" as an option). You can then check the specific countries and carriers you want to use.

Comment: Wow, that's so non-obvious.  When you first publish an app there is just the one checkbox, I never realized I needed to check it, then uncheck it to get all the options.

Comment: I think it is checked by default, though it has been a while and so I may be mistaken.